# TIdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(TStream) cannot send Big5?

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-10.3-rio

Through `TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(StmMsg);`, the message is delivered to the frontend. English is ok, but Big5 cannot be delivered, why!!??

(`StmMsg: TStringStream`, the program has added... `TCPClient.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding:= IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;`)

The following is the code:

```
if not TCPClient.Connected then
TCPClient.Connect;
deviceToken :=
'6aa5bfcfe731ab29b260fab38a43f1e1abac0de3d6e8e0bc5f4b89c422938e8f';
MensajeEnviar := edtMensaje.Text;

strMessage := Get_Msg(deviceToken, Get_PayLoad(MensajeEnviar, 1,
'default'));

StmMsg := TStringStream.Create(strMessage);

StmMsg.Seek(0, soBeginning);
TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(StmMsg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Big5 is not a language. It is a byte encoding used for Chinese.

The `TIdIOHandler.DefStringEncoding` property applies only to *string* operations, not to *stream* operations. The `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` method writes the content of a stream *as-is*. So, it is your responsibility to make sure the contents of the stream are encoded properly beforehand.

However, the `TStringStream` constructor you are calling uses `TEncoding.Default` for the stream's byte encoding. On Windows<sup>1</sup>, `TEncoding.Default` represents the default **ANSI** charset of the user that is running your program. An ANSI charset will not work for Chinese text, and will lose data.

<sup>1: on non-Windows platforms, `TEncoding.Default` uses UTF-8 instead.</sup>

You need to use `TEncoding.UTF8` instead for the stream's byte encoding, eg:

```pascal
StmMsg := TStringStream.Create(strMessage, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

Alternatively, you can remove the stream altogether and just use the `TIdIOHandler.Write(String)` method instead, which will then use the `TIdIOHandler.DefStringEncoding` property, eg:

```pascal
TCPClient.IOHandler.Write(strMessage);
```